# NullPointerException при использовании метода другого класса (Bukkit)

Tags: java

Пытаюсь вызвать файл из другого класса (Ignore), но при запуске выдаёт ошибку (см. ниже)
Главный класс:

```
package seventy.instantwarps;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class Main extends JavaPlugin{
static Main main;

public static Main getInstance() {
    return main;
}

public static Plugin getPlugin() {
    Plugin plug = Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("InstantWarps");
    return plug;
}

/*  File messagesfile = new File(main.getDataFolder(), "messages.yml");
FileConfiguration messages = 
YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(messagesfile); */

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
private List<String> getInstAliases() {
    ArrayList aliases = new ArrayList<>();
    aliases.add("iw");
    return aliases;
}

public void onEnable() {
    Ignore ignoreinst = new Ignore();
    this.getCommand("instantwarp").setExecutor(new IWCommand());
    this.getCommand("instantwarp").setAliases(this.getInstAliases());
/*  if (!messagesfile.exists()) {
        Main.getInstance().saveResource("messages.yml", false);
    } */
    if (!ignoreinst.getFile().exists()) {
        Main.getInstance().saveResource("ignore.yml", false);
    }
}
```

Ignore

```
package seventy.instantwarps;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class Ignore {

public static Ignore ignore;
public static Ignore getIgnore() {
    return ignore;
}

public File getFile() {
    return ignorefile;
}

File ignorefile = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder(),"ignore.yml");
FileConfiguration ignoreconfig = 
YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(ignorefile);
ArrayList<String> playertarget = new ArrayList<>();

public void setIgnore(Player sender, Player target) {
    playertarget.add(target.getName());
    ignoreconfig.set(sender.getName(), playertarget);
}
```

Ошибка

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at seventy.instantwarps.Ignore.(Ignore.java:20) ~[?:?]
>           at seventy.instantwarps.Main.onEnable(Main.java:38) ~[?:?]
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:352) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:416) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:458) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:372) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:440) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:258) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:758) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-4d24e36-5193f76]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static Main main;

public static Main getInstance() {
    return main;
}
```

У вас объект не создается, попробуйте заменить на что-то типа

```
public static Main getInstance() {
    if (main == null) {
        main = new Main();
    }
    return main;
}
```

Comment: При создании экземпляра главного класса выдаёт `Plugin already initialized`

Comment: Если NPE в это строке File ignorefile = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder(),"ignore.yml");
это значит:
1) getInstance() вернул null
2) getDataFolder() вернул null
вынесите инициализацию ignorefile и в отдельные переменные для Instance и DataFolder и залогируйте что выводится